# Generate a nested list of 0's and 1's by comparing two nested lists in python

Tags: python, list, nested

I have two nested lists as below:

```
list_x = [[21, 58, 68, 220, 266, 386, 408, 505, 518, 579], 
          [283, 286, 291, 321, 323, 372, 378, 484, 586, 629]]

list_y = [[21, 220, 386, 505, 518], [286, 291, 321, 323, 372]]
```

I would like to compare elements of the same index position in the above nested lists meaning `list_x[0]` should be compared with `list_y[0]` and so on.

I want to generate a third (nested) list such that for each number in `list_x[0]`, if the number is also in `list_y[0]`, a one is generated and if there is no match, a zero is generated. The same process should be executed for `list_x[1]` and `list_y[1]`.

The length of each sub-list in my nested output list should be 10 (i.e. the length of the longer sub-list, a one where there is a match and a zero if there is no match). All the sub-lists are sorted in ascending order.

Some additional information worth sharing is that `list_y[0]` and `list_y[1]` are subsets of `list_x[0]` and `list_x[1]` respectively.

Therefore the output list that I am seeking should be as follows:

```
out = [[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0], [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]]
```

I tried the following code but I'm getting some 10 extra zeros

```
list_x = [y for x in list_x for y in x] #to flatten list_x

result = []
for y in list_y:
    sublist = []
    for x in list_x:
        if x in y:
            sublist.append(1)
        else: 
            sublist.append(0)
    result.append(sublist)
```

The above code gives me the following:

```
result = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: What is not working with your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas, welcome to SO!

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

list_x = [[21, 58, 68, 220, 266, 386, 408, 505, 518, 579],
          [283, 286, 291, 321, 323, 372, 378, 484, 586, 629]]

list_y = [[21, 220, 386, 505, 518], [286, 291, 321, 323, 372]]

answer=[]
for ( index, inner_list ) in enumerate( list_x ):
  answer.append([])

  for ( inner_index, inner_value ) in enumerate(inner_list):
    answer[index].append(0)
    if inner_value in list_y[ index ]:
      answer[index][inner_index] = 1
print answer
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `zip` to iterate concurrently over the sublists, and then perform an `in` check, like:

```
[[int(x in suby) for x in subx] for subx, suby in zip(list_x, map(set, list_y))]
```

This then yields:

```
>>> [[int(x in suby) for x in subx] for subx, suby in zip(list_x, list_y)]
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The `map(set, list_y)` is used to map all sublists of the `list_y` in sets, since a lookup for a set will usually run in *O(1)*, whereas a lookup in a list takes *O(n)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...You will get your Output

```
    list_x = [[21, 58, 68, 220, 266, 386, 408, 505, 518, 579], 
      [283, 286, 291, 321, 323, 372, 378, 484, 586, 629]]

    list_y = [[21, 220, 386, 505, 518], [286, 291, 321, 323, 372]]
    result =[]
    for ind,lst in enumerate(list_x):
        sublist  =[]
        for ele in lst:
            if ele in list_y[ind]:
                sublist .append(1)
            else:
                sublist .append(0)
         result.append(sublist )
    print(result)
```

Output

```
    [[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0], [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]]
```